# small sample correction in wild cluster bootstrap sandwich & lmtest

Tags: r, cluster-computing, standard-error

I went through the documentation and the source code of `sandwich's` cluster bootstrap function, `vcovBS` in combination with the `coeftest` function from `lmtest`. It looks to me like `coeftest` does not employ any small sample correction. Is that correct? If not, is there a way to impose a small sample correction with the wild cluster bootstrap & `coeftest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct.

The `vcovBS()` method for `lm` objects (the only one supporting wild bootstrap) computes a vector of k coefficient estimates in every one of B bootstrap replications. For the resulting B x k matrix `cf` it just computes the standard Pearson correlation `cov(cf)`.

If you have a pointer to the small sample corrections that should be applied here, I'm willing to have a look. And if so, would these corrections be specific to wild (cluster) bootstrap or apply to xy or residual (cluster) bootstrap as well?